# I'm getting an undefined error after api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, chakra-ui

I'm building a real estate website(off a youtube vid) and im getting undefined erros when fetching data from an api, I should mention that when fetching the data locally everything works fine.

```
export const usePropertyFormat = (property) => {
  const address = property.location.map((item) => item.name).join(", ");
  const coverPhoto = property.coverPhoto.url;
  const propertyType = `${property.category[0].name},${property.category[1].name}`;
  const price = property.price.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  });

  const title = property.title;
  const rooms = property.rooms;
  const baths = property.baths;
  const purpose = property.purpose;
  const sqSize = property.area.toFixed(2);
  const externalID = property.externalID;

  const photos = property.photos?.map((photo) => photo.url) || [];
  const description = property.description;
  const coverVideoUrl = property.coverVideo.url;
  const coverVideo = coverVideoUrl.slice(coverVideoUrl.length - 11);
  const panorama = property.panoramas?.length ? property.panoramas[0].url : [];

  const amenities = property.amenities
    ?.flatMap(({ amenities }) => amenities)
    .map((item) => item && item.text);

  const furnished = property.furnishingStatus;

  return {
    address,
    coverPhoto,
    propertyType,
    price,
    title,
    rooms,
    baths,
    purpose,
    sqSize,
    externalID,
    photos,
    description,
    coverVideo,
    panorama,
    amenities,
    furnished,
  };
};
```

This is the data file.

```
import { axios } from "@/lib/axios";

export const getProperties = async (num) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("/properties/list", {
    params: {
      locationExternalIDs: "5002,6020",
      purpose: "for-sale",
      hitsPerPage: num,
      lang: "en, es",
      sort: "city-level-score",
      hasVideo: true,
      hasFloorPlan: true,
      hasPanorama: true,
    },
  });
  return data.hits;
};
```

This is the api to get the data.

```
import DefaultLayout from "@/features/Layout/DefaultLayout/DefaultLayout";
import { usePropertyFormat } from "@/features/common/Hooks/usePropertyFormat";
import {
  Badge,
  Box,
  Flex,
  Grid,
  GridItem,
  SimpleGrid,
  Text,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { TbMapPin } from "react-icons/tb";
import PropertyThumbnailSlider from "@/features/Property/components/PropertyThumbnailSlider/propertyThumbnailSlider";
import PropertyStats from "@/features/Property/components/PropertyStats/PropertyStats";
import TextContextBox from "@/features/common/modules/TextContentBox/TextContentBox";
import PropertyYoutubeEmbed from "@/features/Property/components/PropertyYoutubeEmbed/PropertyYoutubeEmbed";
import PropertyMatterPortContent from "@/features/Property/components/PropertyMatterPortContent/PropertyMatterPortContent";
import { getProperty } from "@/features/Property/components/api/getProperty";

const PropertySingle = ({ property }) => {
  const {
    address,
    coverPhoto,
    propertyType,
    price,
    title,
    rooms,
    baths,
    purpose,
    sqSize,
    externalID,
    photos,
    description,
    coverVideo,
    panorama,
    amenities,
    furnished,
  } = usePropertyFormat(property);

  return (
    <DefaultLayout>
      <Box backgroundColor="#f7f8f9" paddingY="3rem">
        <Grid
          templateColumns={"repeat(6, 1fr)"}
          gap="5"
          maxWidth={"1280px"}
          margin={"0 auto"}
        >
          <GridItem colSpan={"6"}>
            <Text
              fontSize={"3xl"}
              fontWeight={"medium"}
              color={"blue.800"}
              textAlign={{ base: "center", sm: "left" }}
            >
              {propertyType} {title}
            </Text>
            <Flex
              fontSize={"xl"}
              color={"blue.600"}
              textAlign={"center"}
              alignItems={"center"}
              flexDirection={{ base: "col", sm: "row" }}
              gap={".5rem"}
              marginY={{ base: "1rem", sm: "0" }}
            >
              <TbMapPin />
              <Text fontWeight={"light"}>
                {address} - id:{externalID}
              </Text>
              <Badge colorScheme="green">{purpose}</Badge>
            </Flex>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 6, sm: 3 }}>
            <PropertyThumbnailSlider photos={photos}></PropertyThumbnailSlider>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 6, sm: 3 }}>
            <PropertyStats
              rooms={rooms}
              baths={baths}
              price={price}
              sqSize={sqSize}
            />
            <TextContextBox title="Description">
              <Text
                fontWeight={"light"}
                color={"gray.600"}
                fontSize={"1rem"}
                noOfLines={"4"}
              >
                {description}
              </Text>
            </TextContextBox>
            <TextContextBox title={"Amenities"}>
              <SimpleGrid
                columns={{ base: 1, sm: 2 }}
                fontWeight={"light"}
                color={"gray.600"}
                fontSize={"1rem"}
              >
                {amenities?.length
                  ? amenities.map((item) => <Text>{item}</Text>)
                  : "Please contact us for more info"}
              </SimpleGrid>
            </TextContextBox>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 6, sm: 3 }}>
            <TextContextBox title={"Video Walkthrough"}>
              <PropertyYoutubeEmbed coverVideo={coverVideo} />
            </TextContextBox>
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem colSpan={{ base: 6, sm: 3 }}>
            <TextContextBox title={"3D Tour"}>
              <PropertyMatterPortContent panorama={panorama} />
            </TextContextBox>
          </GridItem>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
};

export default PropertySingle;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { id } = context.query;
  const property = await getProperty(id);
  // const property = require("@/features/data/property");

  return {
    props: { property: property },
  };
}
```

This is the file where I'm using the data.

> Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'map')
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will
> be displayed in the terminal window. Source
> features\common\Hooks\usePropertyFormat.js (2:36) @ map
>
> 1 | export const usePropertyFormat = (property) => {
>
> > 2 | const address = property.location.map((item) => item.name).join(", ");
> > |                                  ^   3 | const coverPhoto = property.coverPhoto.url;   4 | const propertyType =
> > `${property.category[0].name},${property.category[1].name}`;   5 |
> > const price = property.price.toLocaleString("en-US", { Call Stack
> > property pages\properties[id].js (38:24) Show collapsed frames

This is the error im getting.

Im fairly new using react and chakra ui.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Undefined isn’t an error, it’s the value of something that wasn’t defined.  Can you please put the error message that you get into your question, or explain what variable is undefined?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the post and included the error im getting as text.

Comment: So that probably means property.location <-- is undefined.

Comment: `const property = await getProperty(id);`  getProperty returns an object that has no location prop.  Maybe console log it to verify

Comment: When I log getProperty i get promise{<pending>}

Comment: @epascarello but it is defined cause when I do it locally it works

Comment: `export const usePropertyFormat = (property) => { console.log(property);`

Comment: @epascarello Oh i see, so I did that and got all the data. Could that mean that the data is not being loaded quick enough so it is not yet defined at the moment of execution?